# What are the ISO 2375 and 2735 standards mentioned in the ECMA-119 specification?

Tags: standards, ecma, iso9660

Out of ECMA-119 specification:

> 

### 8.5 Supplementary Volume Descriptor

#### ...

#### 8.5.3 Volume Flags (BP 8):

The bits of this field shall be numbered from 0 to 7 starting with the least significant bit.
  This field shall specify certain characteristics of the volume as follows.

Bit 0:

if set to ZERO, shall mean that the Escape Sequences field specifies only escape sequences registered according to ISO **2735**;

if set to ONE, shall mean that the Escape Sequences field specifies at least one escape sequence not registered according to ISO **2375**.

On iso.org I found the ISO-**2735** standard:

> Hermetically sealed metal food containers -- Capacities and diameters of round open-top and vent hole cans for milk

And the ISO **2375** standard:

> Data processing -- Procedure for registration of escape sequences

Could somebody confirm "ISO 2735" as a typing error meant "ISO 2375"? Is there an ECMA standard equivalent to ISO 2375?

Comment: Gosh, this all has shades of Red Dwarf about it! Especially article 39436175880932-B on prisoners of war.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do believe you are correct in that there is a typographical error in Ecma-119. It should be Ecma-2375 where it says Ecma-2735. I will inform Ecma of this issue.

There is no Ecma equivalent to ISO 2375. However, ISO 2375 is referenced in some Ecma specifications, such as Ecma-35 (Character Code Structure and Extension Techniques).

Comment: But (for last part): ECMA 35: "The  registration  procedure  and  the  maintenance  of  the  Register  is  performed  by  an  International  Registration
Authority. ECMA* has been designated by the Council of the International Organization for Standardization, ISO, as the Registration Authority for ISO 2375"